# How to check if a WiFi card supports Transmit Power Control?

Tags: ubuntu, wifi

I have an Atheros wireless PCI card, functioning in AP mode through hostapd.  How can I check whether it supports TPC - and, in this case, turn it on/off?

Note: Transmit Power Control (TPC) is a mechanism used by Wi-Fi emitters to lower signal power in order to reduce interference with other wireless networks.

`iwconfig txpower` sets the transmission power in dBm or mW and it's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same question today. I dug around in the Linux wireless stack code and it seems there is no generic mechanism for controlling or reporting TPC status.

References in driver code to "TPC" appear to be limited to some hard-coded logic telling the hardware to enable it, and possibly sending a "power table" to the firmware to use. The only way to change that requires source code changes and a driver recompilation.

[According to this Cisco document:](https://supportforums.cisco.com/t5/wireless-mobility-documents/tpc-and-dfs-overview/ta-p/3110379)

> Where do you configure TPC?  Well, you don't really configure it. It is part of 802.11h, and your 802.11a device has to be compliant with it, and implements it automatically.

So the answer appears to be: any device that implements 802.11h, supports TPC. Most likely newer standards that build on 802.11h also require TPC.

Disclaimer: I'm not a wireless developer or specialist, so it's well possible that I may be misunderstanding something. Take it with a grain of salt.